# How to parse a datetime string to date object

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following string `String strtime="2013-04-05T12:30:00.000+00:00";`

How do I parse that string into a datetime object? I would like to keep the format!

I know the following things

```
WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("o"));
2013-06-03T19:11:51.7233344+02:00

WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fzzz"));
2013-06-03T19:26:52.7+02:00
```

but I am not sure where to provide the format "o" for my already existing timedate string.

edit:

If I use the simple

```
 datetime = DateTime.Parse(strtime);
 writeLine(datetime.ToString());
```

i get:

```
2013-07-01 12:30:00
```

Some information is missing. I need all the information from the datetime object "`2013-04-05T12:30:00.000+00:00`"

edit2: to provide the bigger picture.
I have to save the string `2013-04-05T12:30:00.000+00:00` to a datetime object and later on i need to save/convert the datetime object again to a string. Both strings, in the end, have to be in the same format `2013-04-05T12:30:00.000+00:00`

I think I have found the solution and wil post it here.
A simple `datetime.ToString()` will cut off information.

```
 WriteLine(datetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz"));
   //2013-02-01T12:30:00.001+01:00
```

Comment: What is wrong with `dateTimeObject = DateTime.Parse("2013-04-05T12:30:00.000+00:00")` ?

Comment: And what "I would like to keep the format" means? `DateTime` is single number, there is no formatting information (and even worse no time zone) associated with it.

Comment: I receive the following: 2013-07-01 12:30:00. No timezone, no milliseconds.

Comment: The `DateTime` object has no concept of format. It stores the required data (e.g. day, month, year etc...) and your formatter, such as `"o"` dictates how the information is displayed.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. The info that "o" is only used to display the time in a specific format was crucial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   datetime = DateTime.Parse("2013-02-01T12:30:00.001+01:00");
   //datetime object shows 2013-02-01 12:30:00 but the ms are still stored. 
   //just use "o"

   WriteLine(datetime.ToString());
   //2013-02-01 12:30:00

   WriteLine(datetime.ToString("o"));
   //2013-02-01T12:30:00.0010000+01:00

   WriteLine(datetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffzzz"));
   //2013-02-01T12:30:00.001+01:00


   String str = datetime.ToString("o");
   WriteLine("my: "+str);
   //my: 2013-02-01T12:30:00.0010000+01:00
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] dateStrings = {"2008-05-01T07:34:42-5:00", 
                              "2008-05-01 7:34:42Z", 
                              "Thu, 01 May 2008 07:34:42 GMT"};
      foreach (string dateString in dateStrings)
      {
         DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
         Console.WriteLine("Converted {0} to {1} time {2}", 
                           dateString, 
                           convertedDate.Kind.ToString(), 
                           convertedDate);
      }                              
   }
}
// These calls to the DateTime.Parse method display the following output: 
//  Converted 2008-05-01T07:34:42-5:00 to Local time 5/1/2008 5:34:42 AM 
//  Converted 2008-05-01 7:34:42Z to Local time 5/1/2008 12:34:42 AM 
//  Converted Thu, 01 May 2008 07:34:42 GMT to Local time 5/1/2008 12:34:42 AM
```

Comment: It's polite to include the source if you've copied code from another site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse.aspx